# Phonegap android get the actual screen size

Tags: android, cordova

I know there are a lot of questions similar to my title but I couldn't find the answer that I want.

In my app, I am using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to get the screen size, but these two values return different size. For example when I run my app on Note 3, I get 360x615 while it should be 1080x1920.

The following code in Java gives me what I want:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
```

So is there any way in Phonegap to get the same screen size value as Java?

Update: when I test the same code on Note 2 with Jelly Beans I get the correct size 720x1230

Comment: do you have a `viewport` meta tag set in your index.html?

Comment: yes,and even if I remove it the result is same.

Comment: If yours is different, try this one `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` I use it in all of my apps and don't have an issue with sizes

Comment: mine have target-densitydpi=device-dpi. I copied yours but still same result. I am now testing on the emulator using Nexus 7 skin (1200x1920) but I am getting 600x887

Answer (score 11):

I am using this code
hope it help you

```
var physicalScreenWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
var physicalScreenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Comment: This worked great for me - I had a slightly different problem where I was trying to determine window.innerHeight during my app's load phase and sometimes that would return zero. I think some portion of screen layout was still happening asynchronously.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you want to figure out the actual device pixels instead of the more commonly measured CSS pizels? You could read up on this [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html).

Basically, if you want to know actual device pixels you could use `screen.width` and `screen.height`. If you want to know CSS pixels you could use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

The meta viewport tag may be ignored on certain Android devices, those are my experiences with Samsung Galaxy tab devices anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure that screen.width and screen.height do actually return pixel values - on a Galaxy S6, screen.height returns 640. It needs to be scaled by window.devicePixelRatio, as Sadegh mentions in his answer.